# Supervised Random Forest in R

Tags: r, random-forest, confusion-matrix

I did an image classification using random forest algorithm in R. I got the result but I do not understand what does the confusion matrix shows ? I mean what does the rows and column show? [image]

These are my classes, and the number of pixels for each class is the number of pixels of the training area of that class, so I do not understand what what are the two elements being compared in confusion matrix?

Comment: I think you're more likely to get a quick response by posting this at the stackoverflow stack exchange or the [stats stack exchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I agree that this post should b moved to cross validated. However here is a short answer. Confusion matrix in general matches actual classes (rows) vs. predicted classes (cols). In your case you can clearly see high error rates in class 9 (85%) and class 105 (48%). To with the random forest performed worst on these two classes. See [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30691/how-to-interpret-oob-and-confusion-matrix-for-random-forest) discussion from Cross-validated about class-errors and validity of `rfor`